# Bootstrap Width issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap version 4.5.
I'm working to create a responsive website I started in Large view as a started then build my way to mobile.
When I resize the website to smaller views it starts to make a large white gap on the right. You can view the website using the following link.
[Website URL](https://zipup.io/)
So, is there any reason for this problem to occur?
I have the following meta too
If you need anything more you can visit the website using the link above.
Note: I tried changing box-sizing & removing padding & margins.

```css
    #tutorials{
    background-image: url("../Images/Header.png");
    background-position: center 0%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#scrollBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 1%;
    right: 5%;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button onclick="backToTop()" id="scrollBtn" class="btn btn-danger m-3" ><i class="fas fa-arrow-up text-white"></i></button>
<main>
                <section id="tutorials" class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center text-white flex-column">
                    <h1 class="display-1">Tutorials</h1>
                    <hr class="w-50 mx-auto hr-header">
                    <p class="lead">Get the latest Tutorials through this page.</p>
                </section>
                <div class="container-fluid">
            
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 mb-5">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://tv.adobe.com/embed/1221/24197/"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h1>Title</h1>
                                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, voluptates.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 mb-5">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://tv.adobe.com/embed/1221/24197/"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h1>Title</h1>
                                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, voluptates.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 mb-5">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://tv.adobe.com/embed/1221/24197/"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h1>Title</h1>
                                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, voluptates.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 mb-5">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://tv.adobe.com/embed/1221/24197/"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h1>Title</h1>
                                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste, voluptates.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
```

Comment: ```row m-5 text-center``` changes to ```row text-center mx-auto```

Comment: Please check @Mohammed Alwedaei it should be fixed width issue

Comment: That helps too Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pro tipp:** Add this `* {outline: red 2px solid;}` somewhere to your css and see the magic happen. It will tell you what elements are overflowing or how big they are. The `outline` won't even shift your content, as it's unlike a `border` not applied to the size of the element.

Once you did that, you will see that there are several issues, all related to overflow. Your `nav-bar` has a `padding-left` and `padding-right` that causes the first overflow to happen.

[image]

Then remove the negative margins here:
[image]

Finally go through these, and remove the additional paddings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: That's great it helps alot Thank you